# Check more fields in Laravel Auth

Tags: laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 .In login i  wanna Check more field such as is_active while users try to login.How can i do that? thanks.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name', 32)->nullable();
        $table->string('last_name', 32)->nullable();
        $table->string('username', 64)->unique();
        $table->string('email', 64)->unique();
        $table->boolean('type')->default(2);
        $table->boolean('is_active')->default(0);
        $table->integer('reputation')->default(0);
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

this is my routes:

```
Route::auth();
Route::post('/login' , 'HomeController@authenticate');
```

how i can use AuthController instead of Home controller?
AuthController is in Auth folder!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As given in laravel [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication)

> Specifying Additional Conditions
>
> If you wish, you also may add extra conditions to the authentication
>   query in addition to the user's e-mail and password. For example, we
>   may verify that user is marked as "is_active":

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'is_active' => 1])) {
            // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
        }
```

### Update:

Add the above code to your Auth Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function authenticate()
    {
        //update
        $email = Input::get('email'); 
        $password = Input::get('password');
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'is_active' => 1 ])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }
}
```

### Update 2:

Keep the authenticate function in `AuthController`, copy it as it is from your `homeController`.

And change the following `Route`

```
Route::post('/login' , 'HomeController@authenticate');
```

To

```
Route::post('/login' , 'Auth\AuthController@authenticate');
```

Comment: where i have to add this code ?

Comment: In the Auth Controller's. Where you are handling the login requests.

Comment: I add it but $email and $password and... are not defined. Do i have to redefine routes and form action and... ?

Comment: Post your auth controller. This was just for illustration purpose, $email and $password and other variables will have to be extracted from the Request

Comment: you are using the default login form of Laravel . right ?

Comment: this is what i did :
make a route:get for login like this:
       Route::post('/login' , 'AuthController@authenticate');
and add your function to home controller like this:
      public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'is_active' => 1 ])) {
            return redirect()->intended('/');
        }
        return redirect()->intended('login');
    }
and every thing worked fine.
just one more question:
how i can move the function to AuthController?
i mean what the route lookes like?

Comment: why home controller ? please update your question with your routes file.

Comment: Check my answer. are you getting it ?

Comment: i did it and this is the error:  ReflectionException in Route.php line 280: Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth/AuthController does not exist

Comment: change `Auth/AuthCotroller` to `Auth\AuthCotroller`

Comment: sorry not working :( same error : Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request does not exist

Comment: in your AuthController add `use Request;` at the top

Comment: not workingggggggggggggggggggg ! => The use statement with non-compound name 'Request' has no effect

Comment: IT WORKED !!!! :D . thank you sooooo soooo soooo much.

Comment: glad I could help... :-)