# PHP Laravel Authentication with retry count

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication, eloquent

I am using php laravel to create an authentication for my Admin Console (Default auth method with eloquent).

For that i have two tables, out of which one is to store the basic user details like username, password, name, retry count, status etc. And the other one with the user role mapping.

What am I trying to achieve

1. Whenever the user try to login, i need check

   - whether the status of the user is active (status = 1)
   - whether the retry count is less than 5 (retry_count < 5)

> Blockquote 
>   This is the SQL query which I am trying to run for the authentication

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '' AND password = '' AND status = 1 AND retry_count < 3;
```

2. If the login fails,

   - Need to redirect to the login page with the proper error messages like "The user account is not activated" or "the user account has been blocked" respectively for the cases in #1
   - Increment the retry_count in the database
3. Once the user is successfully authenticated,

   - I need to store all the details from the roles table into the session so that i can use it to validate whenever necessary.
   - Reset the retry_count to zero
4. When logout, clear all the sessions

Tables

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `password` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `retry_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);  

CREATE TABLE `user_role_mapping` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

> Blockquote
>   The user_role_mapping.user_id is a foreign key to users.id. And the user_role_mapping can have multiple rows for the same user.

I have done the basics for the login authentication like below and it works normally. But I'm stuck here for achieving the above 4 use cases.

```
public function submitLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username'=>'required|max:50',
        'password'=>'required|max:100',
    ]);

    if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password, 'status' => 1])) {

        //return [Auth::user() , Auth::id()];
        return redirect()->intended(route('home'));
    }

    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only('username', 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            'Invalid Username or password.',
        ]);
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803699/check-more-fields-in-laravel-auth) about extra field validation.

"retry count" is included in laravel, check ThrottlesLogins.php, it handles the retry count and clear count on success.

If login failed. check official [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#working-with-error-messages) about error messages. You can do it in blade like this:

```
<input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

@if ($errors->has('email'))
    <span class="help-block">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
    </span>
@endif
```

Laravel will override the error of the email to "Too many login attempts. Please try again in XX seconds." message if too many attempts (default is 5).

You can implement your own action (ex: add more info to session) after an user is authenticated in the function authenticated in AuthenticateUsers.php (Name convention is based on laravel 5.5, didn't check if the name is different for previous version.)

**Be ware of security issue on roles change for logged in users.

```
/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    //below is an exmaple
    $u = User::with('roles')->find($user->id);
    if(isset($u->roles)) {
        foreach($u->roles as $role) {
            session()->put('user.roles.'$role, true);
        }
    }  
}
```

Your 4th question is not a concerned since laravel clears (invalidate) all session for the logged out user. You can check the function logout in AuthenticateUsers.php

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();

    return redirect('/');
}
```

**Update: Throttle for an account from all IPs**

As stated in the login function, Laravel uses username and IP to key in the cache and value for counting. So, at the first glance I will say you are looking for the function throttleKey in [ThrottlesLogins.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/bd17cb29afbb66cb1bcb128d56b71039b9ac7d26/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ThrottlesLogins.php).

```
protected function throttleKey(Request $request)
{
    return Str::lower($request->input($this->username())).'|'.$request->ip();
}
```

Take away .'|'.$request->ip() for global check on all IPs that attempt to login. This is an untested suggestion, and you might need to do more than this to suit your need.

**Update: Validate extra field for login**

In [AuthenticatesUsers.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/bd17cb29afbb66cb1bcb128d56b71039b9ac7d26/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php) look at the function attemptLogin (this is for v5.5)

Here is an example but test is required:

```
/**
 * Attempt to log the user into the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return bool
 */
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = array_add($this->credentials($request), 'status', '1');
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $credentials, $request->has('remember')
    );
}
```

Compare this to the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authenticating-users) you will find the pattern. It's the same as:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) {
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update.
But for the retry count, i have to store count to database to prevent user from accessing the web from any other places if it hits the retry limit.

For the extra field validations, i couldn't find a way to compare the DB field. That is its only check if the value equal to. But i want to check if the retry count is less than 3

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to do a global check every time on a login attempt from different devices or IPs. Well, you can implement it if you dig more into the Laravel's Foundation Class (things like login function in [AuthenticatesUsers.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e6e0e618c216d8f21ebb1d0d8ce21876739e29d9/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php)). However, my first thought is not storing the count in db, but in memcache like redis.

Comment: Comment is not enough for my update. check my answer at the bottom for new update.

Comment: Btw, do not modify laravel foundation class or traits directly unless for a test or learning case. All laravel foundation class will be overridden when you update the Laravel. You can extend them and override the functions in a controller. Or you just make duplicate class and traits for all the things you would modify to your project and write your own auth route.